# Find elements in a Node without the proper namespace, in Java

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-namespaces, nodelist

So I have a xml doc that I've declared here:

```
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory_.newDocumentBuilder();
StringReader reader = new StringReader(s);
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(reader);
doc_ = dBuilder.parse(inputSource);
```

Then I have a function where I pass in a string and I want to match that to an element in my xml:

```
void foo(String str)
{
  NodeList nodelist = doc_.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName(str);
}
```

The problem is when the `str` comes in it doesn't have any sort of namespace in it so the xml that I would be testing would be:

```
<Random>
  <tns:node />
</Random>
```

and the `str` will be node.  So nodelist is now null because its expecting tns:node but I passed in node.  And I know its not good to ignore the namespace but in this instance its fine.  My problem is that I don't know how to search the Node for an element while ignoring the namespace.  I also thought about adding the namespace to the str that comes in but I have no idea how to do that either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks, -Josh

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In order to match all nodes whose name is 'str' regardless of namespace use the following:

```
NodeList nodes = doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagNameNS("*", str);
```

The wildcard "*" will match any namespace.  See [Element.getElementsByTagNameNS(...)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html#getElementsByTagNameNS%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

**Edit**: in addition, how @Wheezil correctly stated in a comment, you have to call `DocumentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true)` for this to work, otherwise namespaces will not be detected.

Comment: Thank you very much for another awesome answer RD01.

Comment: That seems to work only for "namespace-aware" `DocumentBuilderFactory` objects, as DOM level 1-created elements do not have a `localName`...

Comment: Also, if you have a document with items with no namespace at all, it still can't find them... :(

Comment: Does someone notice that if you want to specify the URL of the namespace instead of "*", no elements are returned at all. For instance when I try to match Soap Enveloppe...

Comment: note that you have to call DocumentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true) for this to work.

Comment: It Worked ..but be sure to add    DocumentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true) just after creating the dbfactory obj like    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);