# How to use regular expression in getElementsByTagName method of Java xml Parser

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I have multiple XMLs just varies tag names like this

**sample1.xml**

```
<Customer>
   <ns1:Account>
</Customer>
```

**sample2.xml**

```
<Customer>
   <ns3:Account>
</Customer>
```

**sample3.xml**

```
<Customer>
   <ns5:Account>
</Customer>
```

Account tag is constant but ns value is changing is each xml file. I want to give a regular expression inside `doc.getElementsByTagName` method like ".*child" to write a generic xml function using java xml parser but it is not working. Please help.

```
         File inputFile = new File("input.txt");
         DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
         DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
         Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
         NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName(".*Account");  // giving me null
```

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692605/find-elements-in-a-node-without-the-proper-namespace-in-java) as well.

Comment: Thanks, @FedericoklezCulloca.    I've added it to the duplicate link list.